# I want to create a dynamic iframe using javascript on a button click or a form submit with post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

```
<html>
   <body> 
   <script language="Javascript">
   function actionCalled() {
   var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
   var html = '<body> Hell Iframe </body>';
   iframe.src = "http://example.com";
   iframe.setAttribute("height", "200px");
   iframe.setAttribute("width", "400px");
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  }
</script>
</body>

<button onClick="actionCalled()"> Hello Iframe !</button>
</html>
```

This code I am able to create iframe and url is redirecting to example.com this is just GET method. Same way how can do POST method.

Answer (score 0):

Method POST you can use with out form.

Please view my example how send post data after iframe load

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
       iframe.setAttribute("height", "600px");
       iframe.setAttribute("width", "800px");
    var html = '<body>'+
                '<form id="myform" action="https://example.com" method="post">'+
                '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="123" />'+
            '</form></body>';
    iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    iframe.onload = function() {
       var div=iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('myform').submit();;
    };
    </script>
```

Don't work on old browser like IE  [But i find some hack for IE](http://www.kochan.io/javascript/how-to-dynamically-create-an-iframe.html)